# How to use COM objects in Python 3.x?

Tags: com, python-3.x

I want to access COM objects using Python 3.1, but I can't find a library to support 3.x. Do I need to use some extension or there is something in the standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [PyWin](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) stuff. It provides (among other things, like direct support for Win32 APIs) a COM bridge for Python and now supports both 2.x and 3.x.
Older downloadable releases are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files).
Documentation can be found [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyWin32.html).

Comment: The last version there supports Python 2.6. There is no one for 3.x.

Comment: Edit: added direct link to 3.1 version.